# Android: Does BroadcastManager have queues?

Tags: android

I have a simple BroadcastReceiver that I setup in my onResume method of my Activity.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mNotificationReceiver, new IntentFilter(QuickstartPreferences.NEW_NOTIFICATION));

}
```

I unregister the receiver on onPause:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mNotificationReceiver);
}
```

I have a background service that sends the broadcast message to this:

```
Intent newNotification = new Intent(QuickstartPreferences.NEW_NOTIFICATION);
newNotification.putExtra("title", data.getString("title"));
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(newNotification);
```

My question is, if the background service broadcasts a message when the Activity is not opened and now when the Activity is resumed, will it be able to pick up the broadcasted messages? If no, how to maintain a queue to store broadcasted messages when Activity is not open?

Comment: two options: use `Notification`s or "local bound Service" pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LocalBroadcast is queued but not persisted. In your activity *onPause()* you unregistered receiver so you can not receive further broadcast. the *sendBroadcast()* will check receiver, if there is no reciever it will return false to indicate failure.

If you want always get notification, try to register broadcast at application level rather than activity level.

Answer (score 1):

if the activity is not running then it'll never receive it. what you can do is:

check if your `activity` is `running` before/after you send the broadcast, if its not running then you could store a `sharedPreference` flag that tells your activity when it runs again to do whatever task that it has to do when it `receives` that `broadcast`.